# Build tools v120 error on IntelliJ

Tags: visual-c++, intellij-idea, build, npm, npm-install

I am using the IntelliJ 15.0.1 IDE and after I try to induce this:

```
npm install -g sleep
```

in my project I got this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(44,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for v120 (Platform Toolset = 'v120') cannot be found. To build using the v120 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click
>    the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v120 to build using the v120 build tools.

My question is, can I add this build tool dependency directly in IntelliJ? If yes, how I can do it? Generally what should I do if I use only IntelliJ now.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has no support for updating the version of C++ build tools installed on your machine.

Comment: the solution: run visual studio command prompt -> go to folder which include project open in IntelliJ -> type "npm install -g sleep"